# Sub-arreglo mediante plantilla

Tags: c++, template

El título es algo complicado de entender, así que haré un resumen mediante código. Supongamos que tenemos una plantilla que envuelve un arreglo:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct arreglo
{
    using value_type = T;
    using arreglo_type = arreglo;

    static constexpr auto tamanyo = TAMANYO;
    T datos[tamanyo]{};
};
```

Me gustaría añadir una función a la plantilla `arreglo`, esta función debe devolver un sub-conjunto de los datos de `arreglo::datos`, más o menos como sucede con [`std::string_view`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) de C++17, la función debería saber desde dónde contar el sub-conjunto y cuántos elementos debería tener el sub-conjunto, así que he pensado en una función así:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct arreglo
{
    using value_type = T;
    using arreglo_type = arreglo;

    static constexpr auto tamanyo = TAMANYO;
    T datos[tamanyo]{};

    template <std::size_t INICIO, std::size_t SUB_TAMANYO>
    ???? sub() { ... }
};
```

Escojo la aproximación de plantilla para que el sub-conjunto sea calculado en tiempo de compilación, así que el resultado `????` debería ser un objeto que contenga `SUB_TAMANYO` punteros a los datos de `arreglo::datos`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct arreglo
{
    using value_type = T;
    using arreglo_type = arreglo;

    static constexpr auto tamanyo = TAMANYO;
    T datos[tamanyo]{};

    template <std::size_t INICIO, std::size_t SUB_TAMANYO>
    struct sub_arreglo
    {
        using value_type = arreglo_type::value_type *;

        static constexpr auto inicio      = INICIO;
        static constexpr auto sub_tamanyo = SUB_TAMANYO;

        value_type datos[sub_tamanyo]{};
    };

    template <std::size_t INICIO, std::size_t SUB_TAMANYO>
    sub_arreglo<INICIO, SUB_TAMANYO> sub() { ... }
};
```

Y ahí está el problema: ¿Qué debe ponerse dentro de la función `arreglo::sub`? Estoy casi seguro que debería existir una solución con [`std::integer_sequence`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) pero no tengo experiencia con esa utilidad así que no se cómo enfocarlo. He probado con éxito asumir ambos parámetros de la plantilla `arreglo::sub` como `2`:

```
template <std::size_t INICIO, std::size_t SUB_TAMANYO>
sub_arreglo<INICIO, SUB_TAMANYO> sub() { return { &datos[INICIO], &datos[INICIO + 1u] }; }
```

Lo que permite el siguiente uso:

```
arreglo<int, 9> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

// x es el sub-conjunto [3, 4]
auto x = a.sub<2, 2>();

std::cout << *x.datos[0] << '\n'; // esto muestra 3
```

Así que podemos ver que conceptualmente el cuerpo de `arreglo::sub` debería ser:

```
return { &datos[INICIO + 0], &datos[INICIO + 1], ... &datos[INICIO + n] };
```

¿Cómo podría conseguirse ese efecto con plantillas?

Comment: Dado que los valores del arreglo no son conocidos en tiempo de compilación no es posible generar el subconjunto en tiempo de compilación. Sí que se podría tirar de templates para no tener que escribir el bucle que copiaría el rango, pero no tengo claro que compense. Por otro lado el subrango debería indicar también el tipo de datos

Comment: Y si no es eso hay algo que no estoy entendiendo del todo bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct arreglo
{
    using value_type = T; // (1)
    using arreglo_type = arreglo;

    template <std::size_t INICIO, std::size_t SUB_TAMANYO>
    struct sub_arreglo;
    {
        using value_type = arreglo_type::value_type *; // (2)

        static constexpr auto inicio      = INICIO;
        static constexpr auto sub_tamanyo = SUB_TAMANYO;

        value_type datos[sub_tamanyo]{}; // (3)
    };
};
```

El diseño que estás proponiendo te obligaría a usar `sub_arreglo` de la siguiente forma:

```
struct arreglo<int,10>::sub_arreglo<2,3> x = a.sub<2,2>();
```

Tener las dos estructuras anidadas te puede complicar determinadas operaciones con la clase `sub_arreglo`. Así, puede no ser trivial hacer una comparación entre dos subconjuntos si el arreglo inicial tiene diferente tamaño:

```
arreglo<int,10> a;
arreglo<int,20> b;

arreglo<int,10>::sub_arreglo<2,2> x = a.sub<2,2>();
arreglo<int,20>::sub_arreglo<2,2> y = b.sub<2,2>();

if( x == y ) // x e y son de tipos distintos
  // ...
```

Lo recomendable en este caso es que `sub_arreglo` sea una clase independiente de `arreglo`, de tal forma que:

```
arreglo<int,10> a;
arreglo<int,20> b;

sub_arreglo<int,2,2> x = a.sub<2,2>();
sub_arreglo<int,2,2> y = b.sub<2,2>();

if( x == y ) // x e y son del mismo tipo
  // ...
```

Lo que sucede ahora es que `sub_arreglo` necesita conocer de forma explícita el tipo de datos a los que va a apuntar:

```
template <class T, std::size_t INICIO, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct sub_arreglo
{
  // ...
};
```

El problema que nos podemos encontrar entonces es que si dos `sub_arreglo` tienen inicios diferentes entonces sus tipos van a ser distintos aunque el tamaño sea el mismo:

```
arreglo<int,10> a;
arreglo<int,20> b;

sub_arreglo<int,2,2> x = a.sub<2,2>();
sub_arreglo<int,4,2> y = b.sub<4,2>();

if( x == y ) // x e y son de tipos distintos
  // ...
```

Esto da a entender que la posición de inicio no debería formar parte de `sub_arreglo`:

```
template <class T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct sub_arreglo
{
  // ...
};
```

Comentas que te gustaría que el resultado estuviese calculado en tiempo de compilación. Bien, esto no es posible porque los valores de `arreglo` no son conocidos en tiempo de compilación. Ahí no estás manipulando tipos sino valores editables por el usuario, luego el precálculo en tiempo de compilación no es posible.

Una posible solución sería entonces:

```
template <class T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct sub_arreglo
{
  using value_type = T*;

  static constexpr auto tamanyo     = TAMANYO;

  value_type datos[TAMANYO];

  template<class Iterator>
  sub_arreglo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
  {
    for( auto i = 0; begin!=end; ++begin, ++i)
    {
      datos[i] = &(*begin);
    }
  }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t TAMANYO>
struct arreglo
{
  T datos[TAMANYO];

  static constexpr auto tamanyo = TAMANYO;

  template<size_t INICIO, size_t SUB_TAMANYO>
  sub_arreglo<T,SUB_TAMANYO> sub()
  {
    auto it = std::next(std::begin(datos),INICIO);
    auto itEnd = std::next(it,SUB_TAMANYO);

    return sub_arreglo<T,SUB_TAMANYO>(it,itEnd);
  }
};


int main() {
  arreglo<int,10> a;

  for( auto i=0u; i<a.tamanyo; i++)
    a.datos[i] = i;

  auto x = a.sub<2,2>();

  for( auto i=0u; i<x.tamanyo; i++)
    std::cout << *x.datos[i] << '\n';
}
```

Para crear rangos en tiempo de compilación puedes aprovecharte de los *variadic templates*. Te pongo un ejemplo para sacar rangos de números:

```
template<class T, size_t... Args> struct Array {
    static const T data[sizeof...(Args)];
};

template<class T, size_t... Args>
const T Array<T,Args...>::data[sizeof...(Args)] = { static_cast<T>(Args)... };

template<size_t Contador, class T, size_t Actual, size_t... Args>
struct GeneradorArrayImpl {
    using result = typename GeneradorArrayImpl<Contador-1, T, Actual+1, Args..., Actual>::result;
};

template<class T, size_t Actual, size_t... Args>
struct GeneradorArrayImpl<0, T, Actual, Args...> {
    using result = Array<T, Args...>;
};

template<class T, size_t Inicio, size_t Total>
struct GeneradorArray {
    using type = typename GeneradorArrayImpl<Total,T,Inicio>::result;
};

int main() {
  const size_t inicio = 2;
  const size_t total = 8;
  using array = GeneradorArray<int,inicio,total>::type;

  for (size_t i=0; i<total; ++i)
      std::cout << array::data[i] << '\n';
}
```

¿Cómo funciona el ejemplo anterior? De la siguiente forma:

`GeneradorArray<int,inicio,total>` se convierte en `GeneradorArray<int,2,8>`. `GeneradorArray<int,2,8>::type` se calcula a partir de `GeneradorArrayImpl<8,int,2>::result`. Esta llamada genera la siguiente secuencia recursiva:

- `GeneradorArrayImpl<8,int,2>::result = GeneradorArrayImpl<7,int,3,2>::result`. Para siguientes pasos omito la igualdad por legibilidad
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<7,int,3,2>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<6,int,4,2,3>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<5,int,5,2,3,4>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<4,int,6,2,3,4,5>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<3,int,7,2,3,4,5,6>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<2,int,8,2,3,4,5,6,7>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<1,int,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,9>`
- `GeneradorArrayImpl<0,int,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>`.

El último template de la secuencia anterior se corresponde con la especialización `GeneradorArrayImpl<0,T,Actual,Args...>`, que en nuestro caso será `GeneradorArrayImpl<0,int,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>`. El `result` de este template se calcula llamando a `Array<T,Args...>`, es decir:

```
GeneradorArrayImpl<0,int,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>::result = Array<int,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>
```

Así pues, retrociendo en la secuencia recursiva de `GeneradorArrayImpl`, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
GeneradorArrayImpl<8,int,2,2>::result = Array<int,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>;
```

`Array<>` dispone de un miembro `data` que es un array de tamaño `sizeof...(Args)`, `sizeof...` devuelve el número de elementos en la lista de expansión. La llamada real al template es, en este caso, `Array<int,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>`, lo que implica que la lista de expansión tiene 8 elementos. El arreglo tendrá tamaño 8.

Cuando instanciamos este tipo:

```
using array = GeneradorArray<int,inicio,total>::type; // Creamos un alias por comodidad

for (size_t i=0; i<total; ++i)
  std::cout << array::data[i] << '\n'; // <<--- AQUI se instancia
```

se llama a la inicialización del miembro estático `data`:

```
template<class T, size_t... Args>
const T Array<T,Args...>::data[sizeof...(Args)] = { static_cast<T>(Args)... };
```

Que si lo especializamos queda así:

```
template<int,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>
const int Array<int,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>::data[8] = { static_cast<int>(Args)... };
```

Lo que sucede aquí es lo siguiente:

El código:

```
{ static_cast<int>(Args)... };
```

Se expandirá de la siguiente forma:

```
{ static_cast<int>(2), static_cast<int>(3), ..., static_cast<int>(9) };
```

Es decir, está creando una lista de inicialización con el rango de valores deseado y se lo asigna al array `data`.

Al final del proceso es como si hubiésemos hecho lo siguiente:

```
struct A
{
  static const int data[8];
};

const int data[8] = { 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

int main() {
  const size_t inicio = 2;
  const size_t total = 8;

  for (size_t i=0; i<total; ++i)
      std::cout << A::data[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: *Como norma general, en C++ no es legal que el tipo de retorno dependa directamente de los tipos del template*. Hasta donde yo se es legalísimo, ¿en qué parte del estándar indica que no lo es? Y si no lo es ¿Por qué compila?

Comment: Espera, que especifico un poco más

Comment: Ya está editada la pregutna

Comment: Está editada, mas no responde a nada de lo que he preguntado O_o, de hecho lo que me respondes ya lo sabía :P

Comment: Estoy trabajando en esa parte. De primeras te he solucionado un error que ni tan siquiera sabias que tenías ;)

Comment: Es que no es un error. Ya se que no se pueden sobrecargar funciones sobre su tipo de retorno... mas *sí se puede* usando plantillas: `template <typename T> T func() { return 5;} func<int>(); func<float>();`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, te recomiendo que pruebes el código de tu último comentario en un compilador

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster A ver si esta respuesta te resuelve la duda mejor que la de ayer.

Comment: Nunca dije que fuera un requerimiento que `arreglo<int,10>` y `arreglo<int,20>` fuesen la misma clase ni que fueran comparables entre si. Tampoco veo la mejora sustancial al sacar `sub_arreglo` de `arreglo`. Por otro lado me interesa mucho los ejemplos que has puesto de `GeneradorArray`, necesito estudiarlo con más detalle.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster. Yo tampoco lo he sugerido como un requerimiento. Simplemente hago notar que tener las dos clases anidadas puede no ser la mejor solución

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster aun así podrías anidar ambas clases y la solución que te he puesto seguiría siendo válida (con algunos pequeños retoques)