# Devolver valor por referencia

Tags: c++

Estoy empezando a programar con c++ y me ha surgido una duda al hacer un programa. 
He hecho una clase que pretende gestionar una matriz3d de datos. Para ello, he creado dentro un array lineal y métodos necesarios.
Para gestionar los datos quiero crear un functor que devuelva una referencia a un voxel concreto de la matriz.

Por ejemplo 
a(1,2,3) = 3.0

No estoy del todo seguro si devolver una referencia esta del todo bien para sustituir funciones get y set. El programa va a realizar cálculos matemáticos y me gustaría que la forma que quede en el código sea lo más parecida a la expresión matemática.

añado parte del código:

```
class Grid {
  private:
     int xSize,ysize,zSize;
     double *matriz3D;

  public:
 ... constructores copy constructor move etc.. 

return double& operator()(int xPos, int yPos, zPos){
   if(xPos < 0 || xPos > xSize 
      yPos < 0 || yPos > ySize 
      zPos < 0 || zPos > zSize ){
       trow "Fuera de limites";
     }
   return matriz3d[zPos*xSize*ySize + yPos*xSize + xPos];
  }
 }
}
```

Cualquier comentario o sugerencia es bienvenido.
muchas gracias

Comment: La pregunta es muy interesante a la vez que muy incompleta. Ayudaría mucho que compartieras el código de lo que llevas hecho. Mientras tanto puede que te sea útil [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36868/sub-arreglo-mediante-plantilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, el operador paréntesis (`operator()`) es justo lo que necesitas y funciona como pides. Aún así hay espacio para mejora:

1. **Haz que la clase sea plantilla**: así podrás definir en tiempo de compilación tanto el tipo como los tamaños, las matrices no cambian de tamaño durante las operaciones matemáticas ¿verdad?.
2. **Evita la memoria dinámica**: la memoria dinámica (la creada con el operador `new` es lenta, evítala si puedes), declara una formación de tamaño fijo dentro de tu clase.
3. **Crea un constructor**: vale la pena poder dar valores iniciales a la matriz.
4. **La función de acceso necesita una versión constante**: la versión constante equivale al *get*, la otra versión equivale al *set*.
5. **Al lanzar excepciones, no lances valores**: lanza objetos excepción.
6. **La dimensiones no tienen signo**: no puedes tener tamaños negativos, así que pasa los tamaños a entero sin signo y así además no necesitarás comprobar si el valor es negativo.

> No estoy del todo seguro si devolver una referencia esta del todo bien para sustituir funciones get y set.

Es completamente correcto, y deseable, pero necesitas versiones de lectura (versión constante) y lectura/escritura (versión normal).

Con esas sugerencias tu clase podría parecerse a:

```
template <typename T, unsigned W, unsigned H, unsigned L>
struct Grid
{
    template <typename ... pack>
    Grid(pack ... valores) :
        datos{valores ...}
    {}

    T &operator()(unsigned w, unsigned h, unsigned l)
    {
        if (W < w || H < h || L < l)
            throw std::invalid_argument{"Fuera de limites"};

        return datos[w][h][l];
    }
    const T &operator()(unsigned w, unsigned h, unsigned l) const
    {
        if (W < w || H < h || L < l)
            throw std::invalid_argument{"Fuera de limites"};

        return datos[w][h][l];
    }
private:
    T datos[W][H][L]{};
};
```

Que puede usarse así:

```
using d3x3x3 = Grid<double, 3, 3, 3>;

d3x3x3 a
{
    0., 1., 2.,
    3., 4., 5.,
    6., 7., 8.,

    9., 10., 11.,
    12., 13., 14.,
    15., 16., 17.,

    18., 19., 20.,
    21., 22., 23.,
    24., 25., 26.,
};

std::cout << a(0, 0, 0) << '\n'; // Muestra 0
std::cout << a(1, 1, 1) << '\n'; // Muestra 13
std::cout << a(2, 2, 2) << '\n'; // Muestra 26
```

Y el operador paréntesis, sirve tanto para lectura como para escritura:

```
std::cout << a(0, 1, 2) << '\n'; // Muestra 5
a(0, 1, 2) = 3.;
std::cout << a(0, 1, 2) << '\n'; // Muestra 3
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFNa4NAED3v/oqBQqNgRc1nE5trc8gxkIP1sNUlkeoquiaUkN@ezqyhWBr6AbPw5u1784bdpKoedklyudxlKsnbVEKYlY2upSiWnGtZVLnQSOr3SipRSNg40Kom2ymZwraHVz28XnIc0SYanuss5SfObgxyXRcqkbwtOSOVRdiQB5GXtWxsmHPGUqHL5nSl6PrMGc47c842cF9WskZBbdnWZ/ixt8i@h3PbOFktdVsrMIOjYxzt4yiPFzSSJaVqNPx7Lhjfb9OrOjvgC8xp8e56G0erOFrHp/OCY/FMaShEpiybnoweJUzL9jWXDgy7WoLoYjzXAR9P4DrYDRGN8IxNN0E0xTPDDttHkhq9b679gDBZ/FFHjAmTy592Fn9GDRkDz0gCk0XGYNgRFBeQMZgQQeuzRqfzeVK2GsIQhOU5QGVTN3hRg8U3hY8pWD8oAgzA6iluxfhfJaxHPsHQXfzFc/04D7/icvkA)</kbd>.

Comment: perfecto, tomo nota muchas gracias!!